# Passing parameters in route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

Is there a way to pass parameters into a route ?

I have this :

`<PrivateRoute path="/testpage" component={TestPage} />`

And

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ path, component }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

    return isAuthenticated ? (
        <Route path={path} component={component} />
    ) : (
            <Redirect to="/login" />
        );
};
```

And I want to do something like this (adding myParameter in my route):

```
<PrivateRoute path="/testpage" component={TestPage} myParameter={myParameter} />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change name of component to Component

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ path, Component, myParameter }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

    return isAuthenticated ? (
        <Route path={path} render={() => <Component myParameter={myParameter} />} />
    ) : (
            <Redirect to="/login" />
        );
};
```

How to render you private route:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/testpage" Component={TestPage} myParameter={myParameter} />
```

Comment: Thanks,
It's almost good for me, but now I have a problem :
`<PrivateRoute path="/testpage" Component={TestPage}  currentUser={user}/>
 <PrivateRoute path="/testpage2" Component={ProfilePage}  currentUser={user} />
<PrivateRoute path="/" Component={HomePage}  currentUser={user} />
`

With this configuration now, in all pages, I have the current page + the Homepage displayed (one above the other)

Comment: You have to wrap these private routes with Switch component to choose the first matched route, put your private routes inside This component <Switch>//your private routes here</Switch>. I think my answer helped you to fix the problem, please don't forget to check it.

Comment: Thanks
But now I'm not able to get "id" in "match" if I have a route like this 
`<PrivateRoute path="/mypage/:id" Component={TestPage} currentUser={user} />`

Comment: You should open a new question because the main problem of your question (adding param to your page) is solved, please don't forget to check it, and give me the link to your new question.

Comment: OK I'll do
Thanks