# Get an id from a path in a specific route

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm not able to get "id" in "match" if I have a route like this

`<PrivateRoute path="/mypage/:id" Component={TestPage} currentUser={user} />`

My private route is

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ path, Component, myParameter }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

    return isAuthenticated ? (
        <Route path={path} render={() => <Component myParameter={myParameter} />} />
    ) : (
            <Redirect to="/login" />
        );
};
```

Before I was able to get id using match, before I made changes recommended for me in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692296/passing-parameters-in-route)

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to get the param id by using the hook useParam ?
const { id } = useParams() ?

Comment: can you please add more details how you are trying to access id

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil No... How to use it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative way to pass props to your page, if you are using render in your route:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ path, Component, myParameter }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

    return isAuthenticated ? (
        <Route path={path} render={(props) => <Component myParameter={myParameter} {..props} />} />
    ) : (
            <Redirect to="/login" />
        );
};
```

On your page component, you can access your param by using props:

```
const { id } = props.match.params
```